# Yii 1 - listData() & dropdownList()

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii, yii1.x

I have this code:

```
$vehicleList = CHtml::listData(Vehicle::model()->findAllByAttributes(
        array(
            'user_id'=>$company->user_id,
            'status'=>1,'archived'=>0, 'deleted'=>0
        )
    ),
    'id', 'vehicle_model'
);
```

And that code:

```
<?php echo CHtml::activeDropDownList(
    $jobEvent,
    'vehicle_id',
    $vehicleList,
    array(
        'empty'=>'',
        'options'=>$vehicleListOptions,
    ));
?>
```

That generate the output like this:

```
<option value="45" class="option_45">Alfa 159 </option>
```

From the `Vehicle::model()->findAllByAttributes()`
I want to get other attributes as `License Plate` and `Vehicle Description`
to make an output like this:

```
<option value="45" class="option_45">Alfa 159 (License Plate ) <br> Vehicle Description </option>
```

Any idea?

Comment: can you show what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Closure to generate such description:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::model()->findAllByAttributes([
    'user_id' => $company->user_id,
    'status' => 1, 'archived' => 0, 'deleted' => 0,
]);
$vehicleList = CHtml::listData($vehicles, 'id', function ($model) {
    /* @var $model Vehicle */
    return "{$model->vehicle_model} ({$model->license_plate}) {$model->vehicle_description}";
});
```

You can find more info in [documentation of this method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail).

Comment: Thank you Rob!
i'm new to coding, not really understand where did you get the $module variable?

Comment: Do you mean `$model`? It is passed as an argument to anonymous function by `CHtml::listData()`. I added link to documentation - there is similar example there.

Comment: @AlexandrMisiyuk please check the source code of `\CHtml::listData()`: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L2289 and `\CHtml::value()`: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/helpers/CHtml.php#L2346 which is used by `\CHtml::listData()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually i've solved my request int his way

```
 $vehicleList = CHtml::listData(Vehicle::model()->findAllByAttributes(
                    array(
                        'user_id'=>$company->user_id,
                        'status'=>1,'archived'=>0, 'deleted'=>0
                    ),
                    array("select"=>"id,concat(vehicle_model ,' ( ', license_plate ,' ) - ', vehicle_description) as vehicle_model")
                ),
                    'id', 'vehicle_model'
                );
```

by adding a new array row

**array("select"=>"id,concat(vehicle_model ,' ( ', license_plate ,' ) - ', vehicle_description) as vehicle_model") ),**

i'm trying to add a new line after (license_plate) by adding "\n", varchar(13).. but it doesn't works..